# Receiving power notifications (especially shutdown) on Mac OSX

Tags: c, macos, shutdown

I'm writing an application in C for the Mac (Leopard) that needs to do some work on receipt of power notifications, e.g. sleep, wake-up, shutdown, restart. It runs via `launchd` as a launchagent on login then begins monitoring for notifications. The code I'm using to do this is as follows:

```
/* ask for power notifications */
static void StartPowerNotification(void)
{
    static io_connect_t rootPort;   
    IONotificationPortRef notificationPort;
    io_object_t notifier;

    rootPort = IORegisterForSystemPower(&rootPort, &notificationPort, 
                                        PowerCallback, &notifier);
    if (!rootPort) 
        exit (1);

    CFRunLoopAddSource (CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),  
                        IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(notificationPort), 
                        kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
}

/* perform actions on receipt of power notifications */
void PowerCallback (void *rootPort, io_service_t y, 
                    natural_t msgType, void *msgArgument)
{
    switch (msgType) 
    {
        case kIOMessageSystemWillSleep:
            /* perform sleep actions */
            break;

        case kIOMessageSystemHasPoweredOn:
            /* perform wakeup actions */
            break;

        case kIOMessageSystemWillRestart:
            /* perform restart actions */
            break;

        case kIOMessageSystemWillPowerOff:
            /* perform shutdown actions */
            break;
    }
}
```

However, only the top two for sleep and wake (`kIOMessageSystemWillSleep` and `kIOMessageSystemHasPoweredOn`) **ever** get called. I never get any notifcations for restart or shutdown (`kIOMessageSystemWillRestart` and `kIOMessageSystemWillPowerOff`).

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another API that would give me the restart and shutdown notifications? I'd prefer to keep it as a C program (as thats what I'm familiar with) but am open to any sensible suggestions of alternatives (I've had a look at login/logout hooks but these seem to be deprecated in favour of launchd).

Thanks in advance for any help/tips!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you can register for the NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification notification from NSWorkspace, which is not a C function but does work.

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import "WorkspaceResponder.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
    WorkspaceResponder *mainController = [[WorkspaceResponder alloc] init];

    //register for shutdown notications
    [nc addObserver:mainController
selector:@selector(computerWillShutDownNotification:)
          name:NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification object:nil];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Then in WorkspaceResponder.m:

```
- (void) computerWillShutDownNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Received Shutdown Notification");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Do you know if I need a window or dock icon in order to receive these notifications?

Comment: Thanks again Rob, thats much appreciated.

Comment: I tried the above solution with no luck. Running a Foundation tool as a LaunchDeamon, but I linked against AppKit just to try this. Doesn't seem shutdown is ever hit... is it not supported here?

Comment: The code in this answer looks correct but the notification will not be sent to a daemon process -- the code would work fine for an application.

Comment: The original poster states his command-line tool *runs via launchd as a launchagent on login*. This means it is a user-space Launch Agent, not a Daemon, and it ***will*** receive notifications. If the tool were executed as a system-wide Launch Agent or Daemon then I would agree with you.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while.. but perhaps do you know if this method still works on modern macOS versions ? it seems like the following question represents a failed attempt to get those events https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085718/nsworkspacewillpoweroffnotification-never-called/47583949#47583949

Comment: @IradK it will work if you run it as a `LaunchAgent`, not as a `LaunchDaemon`. `LaunchDaemon` processes are faceless and can't use AppKit. See my comment above.

Comment: @ctpenrose, It's indeed the case here. I just got a daemon that hold mount drive, and if I unmount it gracefully, the shutdown flow become much faster. I don't want to use agent instead, since this deamon is a singleton for the entire station (no per-user process).. perhaps you can advise me how to get this event anyway ? Thanks !

Comment: @IradK you can still run as a `LaunchAgent` system-wide. That's why there is a `/Library/LaunchAgents/` folder as well as the user-specific `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` folder.

Comment: @IradK and anyone else here, did you find out how to receive these notifications from a launch daemon? Am facing the same problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Using `IORegisterForSystemPower` doesn't provide the events you seek. Quoting from function documentation :

> /*! @function       IORegisterForSystemPower
>
> @abstract       Connects the caller to the Root Power Domain IOService 
>   for the purpose of receiving sleep & wake notifications for the system.
>
> Does not provide system shutdown and restart notifications.