# Time of shutdown on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Receiving power notifications (especially shutdown) on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321219/receiving-power-notifications-especially-shutdown-on-mac-osx)

Hi Guys,

I'd like to be able to log the times that my mac is switched on and off during the day (keeping track of my hours jacked-in). Switched on is easy: I just have a tiny script that writes the time to a logfile when the user logs on, but I can't find a way of record the time that the Mac powers down.

Any Ideas? I'm not particularly bother about non-standard shutdowns and the like, just really want to get a small script to run on shutdown...

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321219/receiving-power-notifications-especially-shutdown-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just interesting it the dates of the events (not necessarily running a script), try `last reboot shutdown` in *Terminal*.

The “reboot” entries are when the system was started. The “shutdown” entries are when it was shutdown.