# Detect shutdown/reboot in OSX from C++ app

Tags: c++, macos, shutdown, reboot, shutdown-hook

How can I detect a shutdown/reboot on OSX from a C++ application?

I need to report that the system is gonna shutdown/reboot to a central server sending a packet so it should be fast enough so network interfaces don't go down before the packet is sent.

Thanks

Comment: Not quite a duplicate - asked with [c] tag, answered with Objective-C.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321219

Comment: Yes, I saw that one but I need to use C or C++ :)

Comment: This question has nothing to with C++, it's a question about APIs and calls provided by OS.

Comment: I want to do it with C++ and not with cocoa (that's already answered) so yes, it has something to do with it

Comment: @user1618465: I think you are missing Sergey's point. This question has nothing to do with C++ the language (as C++ absolutely nowhere in the standard talks about hardware or OS requirements; this is unlike coco that does build in some OS/Hardware into the language). The problem is an OS one. What API does the OS provided you that notifies you of a shutdown. You have to know this API so that you can call it from C++.

Comment: I would bet this is a signal sent to each running ap by the OS just prior to shutdown. You may want to search SO for shutdown signal from the OS.

Comment: That other question's answer uses `NSNotificationCenter`, but I bet you could use `CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter` and `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver` using toll-free bridging.